# How do I get the absolute path of an INI file with Delphi?

Tags: delphi, winapi, ini

If I use this Delphi code

```
with TIniFile.Create('myapp.ini') do
try
  WriteString('SETTINGS', 'key', 'value');
finally
  Free;
end;
```

to create a INI file in the default folder, is there a way to retrieve the absolute path which is used by Windows to create the file?

Comment: why don't you set the default path as the same as application path? For example using `TIniFile.Create(changefilext(paramstr(0),'.ini'))` will place your ini file on the same folder as your executable file.

Comment: @theodorusap and break every rule concerning UAC?

Comment: You are surely doing this all wrong. You really must stop putting files in the Windows directory, or relying on virtualization. In fact, you really ought to stop using the long deprecated Win16 back compat APIs. Don't ask what the full path is, provide the full path. And switch to `TMemIniFile`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes, this problem only appeared during a legacy application migration. Almost everywhere the INI files have been created with a full path to a specific settings folder, so the solution was to fix the single location where it used the code shown in the question.

Comment: You really should stop using `TIniFile` too. The documentation says: *This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows.*

Comment: INI files are not such a bad idea, but using the Win16 back compat functions is. They are full of weird compat shims. `TMemIniFile` avoids that. And is way faster. `TIniFile` can be a perf issue.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan good hint, I wish the Delphi docwiki indicated OS-specific compatibility classes and their modern replacements more clearly, for example wit a '16 bit' icon on the class overview page

Comment: I would think a good place for an INI file would be to use `System.IOUtils.TPath.GetHomePath` which "Returns either the home path of the user or the application's writable scratch directory or storage..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In background, `TInifile.WriteString` uses the [`WritePrivateProfileString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725501(v=vs.85).aspx) function.

from the documentation (emphasis mine):

> ```
> BOOL WINAPI WritePrivateProfileString(   _In_ LPCTSTR lpAppName,  
>     _In_ LPCTSTR lpKeyName,   _In_ LPCTSTR lpString,   
>     _In_ LPCTSTR lpFileName );
> ```
>
> `lpAppName` [in]
>
> The name of the section to which the string will be copied. If the
>   section does not exist, it is created. The name of the section is
>   case-independent; the string can be any combination of uppercase and
>   lowercase letters.
>
> `lpKeyName` [in] The name of the key to be associated
>   with a string. If the key does not exist in the specified section, it
>   is created. If this parameter is NULL, the entire section, including
>   all entries within the section, is deleted.
>
> `lpString` [in] A null-terminated string to be written to the file. If
>   this parameter is NULL, the key pointed to by the lpKeyName parameter
>   is deleted.
>
> `lpFileName` [in] The name of the initialization file. If the file was
>   created using Unicode characters, the function writes Unicode
>   characters to the file. Otherwise, the function writes ANSI
>   characters.
>
> **If the lpFileName parameter does not contain a full path and file name for the file, WritePrivateProfileString searches the Windows
>   directory for the file. If the file does not exist, this function
>   creates the file in the Windows directory.**

This last comment implies that your program must be run as administrator. Logical consequence is that if your program is not run as an administrator, the default path would be `C:\Users\Windows username\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Windows`.
So to abide modern windows rules, it is best practice to supply a full path for the ini file...

Comment: `This last comment implies that your program must be run as administrator` - unless the application runs for example in a terminal services environment which maps (certain) files to a virtual Windows directory